# CSS / jQuery: How to prevent tooltip from disappearing behind border of main wrapper (working code)

Tags: jquery, css, position, tooltip

I am new to CSS and hope someone can help me with this.

I am trying to **create a tooltip for on-hover display**. It needs to be able to show HTML content so I cannot use the title attribute approach and I don't want to use a plugin for this.

So far I have the below which works in general, i.e. the layout and content is as intended and it appears on hover etc. 
However, I **am facing one problem here** that I cannot figure out myself:
If I test this on a smaller screen size then a part of my tooltip disappears behind the right border of my main page wrapper so half of the tooltip gets hidden behind that.

**Is there a way that I can set this so that the tooltip width goes max till the right border of the main wrapper** and then extends its height instead of its width ?
I tried using `overflow` and `z-index` here but still couldnt' get this to work. 
On the other hand I had to use white-space: nowrap as otherwise I am getting tooltips with a large height but very small width.

**My CSS:**

```
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip span {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666;
    color: #fff;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
}
.tooltip span:after {
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid blue;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 16px;
    width: 0;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    top: 50%;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**Sample HTML:**

```
<div class="col-12 tooltip">
    <input type="text" required />
    <span>
        <strong>Some text</strong><br />
        <ul>
            <li> Some text</li>
            <li> Some text</li>
            <li> Some text</li>
            <li> Some text</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Update:**
If jQuery is the better approach for this please let me know as well.

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: Will the tooltips always be to the right, left or center of the page? Regardless of viewport size so their position within the page is predictable? If so you might have to sub class out the positioning part of your tooltip CSS, ie `.tooltip.left`, `.tooltip.right`, `.tooltip.center`. If the tooltips will change what side of the page they are on at various viewport sizes then you will have to incorporate some JS.

Comment: Can you provide the tooltip content?

Comment: @hungerstar: Thanks. The tooltip will always be needed to appear on the right side of the element to which it is attached. I think using JS here might be a good idea. Can you let me know what I would have to do there to calculate this ?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J.: The tooltip content varies and will usually be a small text. The example I used for testing contained a small and simple unordered list. I will add this to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **@media**:

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/k7fmu0qd/).**

**E.g.**

```
@media (max-width: 350px) {
    .tooltip span:after {
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 8px solid blue;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        content: '';
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 30%;
        top: -8px;
        width: 0;
    }

    .tooltip:hover span {
        left: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

Just change the styles of **tooltip** class inside the **@media**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much and sorry for the late reply - this is awesome ! :)